# Comunicar servicio de windows con Aplicacion de escritorio C#

Tags: c#, .net, socket, servicio

Me pueden ayudar a comunicar un servicio de windows con una aplicación C# de escritorio. Actualmente lo realizo por medio de un socket dado que no son muchos los datos que envió. En si el servicio almacena la información en la base de datos y me manda las acciones que se realizaron.

¿No se si hay otra forma de comunicar la interfaz con el servicio o si esta sea la manera mas óptima?

Answer (score 1):

Si quieres algo mas `real time` y ademas `actualizado tecnologicamente` podrias implementar `SignalR`

Si bien es una tecnologia que se asocia a desarollos `web` puede aplicarse con `winforms`

[Using SignalR in WinForms and WPF](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/Using-SignalR-in-WinForms-f1ec847b)

de esa forma tanto `servicio de windows` como `app winfoms` estaran comunicandose mediante un canal establecido enviandose los datos

En el ejmeplo veras como se crea un `Hub` que lo expone el servidor

```
public class MyHub : Hub 
{ 
    public void Send(string name, string message) 
    { 
        Clients.All.addMessage(name, message); 
    } 
    public override Task OnConnected() 
    { 
        Program.MainForm.WriteToConsole("Client connected: " + Context.ConnectionId); 
        return base.OnConnected(); 
    } 
    public override Task OnDisconnected() 
    { 
        Program.MainForm.WriteToConsole("Client disconnected: " + Context.ConnectionId); 
        return base.OnDisconnected(); 
    } 
}
```

Y los clientes se subscribesn para recibir los eventos

```
HubProxy.On<string, string>("AddMessage", (name, message) => 
    this.Invoke((Action)(() => 
        RichTextBoxConsole.AppendText( 
            String.Format({0}: {1}" + Environment.NewLine, name, message)) 
        )) 
);
```

si bien por debajo se sigue usando socket y demas tecnologia de red, esta implementacion te abstrae de eso y permite que te enfoques en la funcionalidad enviando mensajes en eventos